# Get most approximated value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with rows fruit and price for example:

```
Apple - 1

Melon - 3

Orange - 10

Pear - 5
```

And I want to make a query to get the fruit with price more approximated to the value I will pass.

Something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM fruit
WHERE condition
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show examples of the value and the corresponding result? Maybe just `select name from fruit where price < 4` ?

Comment: My code will do a lot of querys with different 'price'. I put this only for example, the real problem is that I have contracts and depending on the amount of it I will recommend similar contract with more approximated value to the value of first contract. @Corion

Comment: Then you didn't made a good user case with example data..

Comment: Maybe you want to find the "closest" price? Like, if the current contract is valued at 7, you want to recommend Orange or Pear? Please, show us some examples of what you mean...

Comment: Imagine I want to get the value of fruit with price more approximated to 4, how you should do it? @RaymondNijland

Comment: Most likely like @Corion said a simple `WHERE column [<|>] 1 [, ...] ORDER BY column [ASC|DESC] [, ...]  LIMIT 1`

Comment: @Corion yes! I want to find the closest price, so if the current contract is valued at 7 the query should recommend pear.

Comment: Oh you want to have one record always which is closed to 4 it does not matter if price is higher or lower then 4 .. What MySQL Version do you have?

Comment: Just use the `ABS()` function: `select abs(price-4) as distance, name from fruits order by distance limit 1`

Comment: assuming prices are always positive in his table then yes `ABS()` will work in your query @Corion

Comment: Prices are always positive, yes!
I will try it @Corion

Comment: Not sure `abs(price-4)` might be changed into `abs(price) - 4` to get correct results now i think about it.. @Corion .. MySQL documentation says `ABS(X) Returns the absolute value of X. ` not  `ABS(expression)` which could indicate ABS can work with SQL expression input.

Comment: No, if price is 5, and your value is 6, you want a distance of 1. If your value is 4, you also want a distance of 1. So it must be `abs(price-4)` and `abs(price-6)`.

Comment: Never mind `ABS()` can work with SQL expressions which was not mentioned in the MySQL manual @Corion .. By the way `select abs(5 - 4);` and `select abs(5) - 4;` both give the same results when positive numbers are used with negative number you get a difference.

Comment: Sure, but `select abs(3 - 4)` and `select abs(3)-4` give different results :)

Comment: indeed @Corion forget to mention the negative number part before your comment.

Comment: When you get to 17 comments, it's time to delete and start over

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM fruit f
ORDER BY ABS(f.price - 7)
LIMIT 1;
```

This gets the fruit whose price is closest to 7.  Of course, "7" is a parameter that could be any value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the comments pretty much have the answer:

```
SELECT * FROM fruit  
WHERE abs(price-@searchprice) =
  (SELECT abs(price-@searchprice) 
  FROM fruit ORDER BY abs(price-@searchprice) LIMIT 1)
```

The subquery finds the price difference from the entered price (@searchprice - change the parameter name style according to the needs of your database/driver combination) to the nearest 1 actual price

This is then used to look up all fruit that has a difference equal to that price difference. We do this so that any items tied on price are returned - in your example data if searchprice was 2 then Apple and Melon are both equally near and should be returned